# Remember Me functionality in Salesforce Community Custom VF Login Page

Tags: visualforce, community, login

I have a custom VF page as login for our customer community. How can I implement Remember Me functionality similar to the default login page in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use browser cookie to store your username and password.

You can use javacsript to store username and password in browser cookie . and later when view this page again in Vf page. get the username and password from browser cookie.

Create cookies

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

> ## **A Function to Set a Cookie**
>
> First, we create a function that stores the name of the visitor in a cookie variable:
>
> Example
>
> ```
> function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
>     var d = new Date();
>     d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
>     var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
>     document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
> }
> ```
>
> Example explained:
>
> The parameters of the function above are the name of the cookie
>   (cname), the value of the cookie (cvalue), and the number of days
>   until the cookie should expire (exdays).
>
> The function sets a cookie by adding together the cookiename, the
>   cookie value, and the expires string.
>
> ## **A Function to Get a Cookie**
>
> Then, we create a function that returns the
>   value of a specified cookie:
>
> Example
>
> ```
> function getCookie(cname) {
>     var name = cname + "=";
>     var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
>     var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
>     for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
>         var c = ca[i];
>         while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
>             c = c.substring(1);
>         }
>         if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
>             return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
>         }
>     }
>     return "";
> }
> ```
>
> Function explained:
>
> Take the cookiename as parameter (cname).
>
> Create a variable (name) with the text to search for (cname + "=").
>
> Decode the cookie string, to handle cookies with special characters,
>   e.g. '$'
>
> Split document.cookie on semicolons into an array called ca (ca =
>   decodedCookie.split(';')).
>
> Loop through the ca array (i = 0; i < ca.length; i++), and read out
>   each value c = ca[i]).
>
> If the cookie is found (c.indexOf(name) == 0), return the value of the
>   cookie (c.substring(name.length, c.length).
>
> If the cookie is not found, return "".